# Devise Omniauth callback error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, devise, omniauth

I have a web application running Devise and Omniauth to authenticate a user on Facebook. When I click on a link to log in though Facebook, it routes me to

```
/users/auth/facebook/callback?state=[state]code=[code]
```

Which is correct. But the page gives me the following error.

```
uninitialized constant ApplicationController::DeviseController
```

The line that it points to is in the ApplicationController

```
DeviseController.respond_to :html, :json
```

I've included my relevant code here https://gist.github.com/testrecord/5050992 In addition, I do have it set up in the initializer.

Has anyone seen an error like this? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It looks like rails is unable to locate the DeviseController class -- meaning it's somehow not available from your ApplicationController. Is it in your Gemfile? Can you confirm that your Devise initializer is running correctly?

Comment: I can verify that I can log in using the normal devise setup and also use Google OpenID through devise. I'm not sure I know exactly how to provide any additional verification.

Comment: Does DeviseController should be in ApplicationController namespace?
Did you try to call it with `::DeviseController`?

Comment: I actually did try that. It gives me the same error, but changed as  "uninitialized constant DeviseController".